# getting an error while mapped items to navigate to another page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to this concept i am trying to map the items and in that i want make each and every item should navigate to another page. But I am getting an error while doing that .. Please help me with this !

i want to know how to navigate the each item to another page when you click on it and it should be a different page for every items in the list .

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ItemsData from "../components/Item";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getAllItems } from "../actions/itemActions";
import "./Homepage.css";
export default function Homepage() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch(); // by this var we can dispatch the action.

  const itemsstate = useSelector((state) => state.getAllItemsReducer);
  // destructured the var
  const { items, error, loading } = itemsstate; // with this help of var we can track whether it is loading or error whether we got the response about items.
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllItems());
  }, []);

  return (
    // we are using the conditional rendering.
    <div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-12 px-0 d-flex flex-lg-row flex-md-row flex-column justify-content-between flex-wrap">
          {loading ? (
            <h1>Loading...</h1>
          ) : error ? (
            <h1>Something went Wrong </h1>
          ) : (
            items.map((items) => {
              // data comes from backend.
              return (
                <div className="col-md-4" key={items._id}>
                  <div>
                    <ItemsData items={items} />
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What is the error? Can you clarify what you mean by "i want to know how to navigate the each item to another page when you click"? Do you mean you want there to be a link somewhere linking to a `Route` rendering some specific content?

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to include the routes you are trying to link to, and where exactly you want the links? Is `ItemsData` rendering the links?

Comment: the post is edited can you help me out with this issue. Is there any referral link's for better understanding the concept's of mapped  items for navigating it to another page.

Comment: There are no `"/shows"` or `"/places"` routes. What are the "1st" and "2nd" items being clicked on that you refer to?

Comment: I explained with that examples for better understanding.

Comment: We need more explicit/specific examples for what you are *actually* trying to do in code. You've also still not explained or shared what the error is/was.

Comment: can you please show the **ItemsData** component code. it will help me a lot so solve you problem.

Answer (score -1):

map() function iterates through your array and returns a new array.
The callback you use can access up to 3 parameters, the 1st one being the element being iterated.
In your case you're naming your element also `items`, this can be confusing to Javascript not knowing which `items.id` to pass to the key and `items` to pass to ItemsData

Changing the element to `item` should solve your problem

Also consider changing the name of the prop in your ItemsData, because that component should receive 1 item at a time, not multiple

```
items.map((item) => {
  // data comes from backend.
  return (
    <div className="col-md-4" key={item._id}>
      <div>
        <ItemsData items={item} /> //probably consider changing this prop name
      </div>
    </div>
  );
})
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, Can you help me with how to navigate to another page for this Mapped items. How can i give different page navigation to each item in the list? example if i have 6 items when i clicked on 1st item i should show some data regarding 1st item. In the same way i need to do it for remaining items also, How can I archive it